# List of Class/Methode Calls

Tags: c#, list, class, reference

Is it possible to get a list with the calls of a method or a class?

example:

```
test(1);
test(2);
public void test(int i){
}
```

"test" has 2 calls. How can i get them to a list or array automatically?

Comment: Do you ask about number of times ``test()`` is called during execution or number of times ``test()`` call is encountered in source code? Say, in ``for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) test(i);`` what will your hypothetical array be?

Comment: In what context?  As a one-time exercise, you can right-click on the method in Visual Studio and "find all references".  As a static report, you can use code analysis tools.  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Are you trying to count how many times `test` gets called? You could use a static variable.

Comment: This is difficult especially at release time with method inlining. There are design-time components like CodeLens that can tell you how many references there are to a particular method. Do you need this for precompile time, or during runtime?

Comment: You want to implement a profiler I guess. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15410/Creating-a-Custom-NET-Profiler)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want and sizes of problem.

1. If you want to watch usings of the method in code - you can use Find Usages in Visaul Studio
2. If you want to count only one method calls - in small project - you can use static variable.
3. If you have to collect some kind of complicated metrics - you can use some kind of interception to interface calls - for example unity interception https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx